# Rails server is not starting due to invalid argument (errorno::EINVAL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ruby-2.3

I'm facing this problem while starting rails server.

**ruby: 2.3.1**

**rails: 5.0.0.1**

ubuntu 14.04 in windows linux subsystem. Thanks in advance.

```
        /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/watcher.rb:74:in `initialize': Invalid argument - Failed to watch "/home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/locale": the given event mask contains no legal events; or fd is not an inotify file descriptor. (Errno::EINVAL)
        from /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:190:in `new'
        from /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:190:in `watch'
        from /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:204:in `watch'
        from /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/linux.rb:32:in `_configure'
        from /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:45:in `block in configure'
        from /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:40:in `each'
        from /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:40:in `configure'
        from /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:63:in `start'
        from /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/backend.rb:28:in `start'
        from /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/listener.rb:67:in `block in <class:Listener>'
        from /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/fsm.rb:120:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/fsm.rb:120:in `call'
        from /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/fsm.rb:91:in `transition_with_callbacks!'
        from /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/fsm.rb:57:in `transition'
        from /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/listener.rb:90:in `start'
        from /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:90:in `boot!'
        from /home/devs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:61:in `initialize'
```

Comment: Please see this issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26054

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to you config/environments/development.rb and comment out The Line
 **config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker**, After run bundle exec rails s.

Comment: This happens to me on rails in 2017, in ubuntu bash in windows subsystem for linux.

Comment: @WarrenP I've just ran into this error on WSL too. Did you fix it?